# VBA looking for error values in a specific column

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Macro9()
Dim LReturnValue As Boolean

LReturnValue = IsError(Sheets("Lookup Addition").Range("A:A").Value)

If LReturnValue = False Then
    i = MsgBox("there were no errors", vbOKOnly)
Else
    i = MsgBox("there were errors", vbOKOnly)
End If

End Sub
```

I am a little confused as to what the IsError(Customfunction()) syntax should be.  how do we tell it to check every cell in the the range?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. Do you want to simply return `True` if there are **any** error values in the range? In any case you'll have to iterate over the range.  I will post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Counting errors in a range doesn't require looping (which can be very slow if the range is large) or even any VBA.

Just add this worksheet function to a cell somewhere.  If you don't want the user to see this cell, you can hide the row/column/sheet.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISERROR(A:A)*(1=1))
```

If you still want a pop-up box for the user, your VBA will now be:

```
Sub CountErr()  
     MsgBox "There are " & ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value & " Errors"  
End Sub
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `Evaluate` and the worksheet function `COUNTIF` to count the # of errors:

```
Sub CheckRangeForErrors()

    Dim errCount As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim col As String

    col = Application.InputBox("Enter the column letter you would like to check for errors", "Column Name?")

    If Not Len(col) = 1 Then
        MsgBox "You have entered an invalid selection", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rng = Sheets("Lookup Addition").Range(col & "1", Range(col & "1048576").End(xlUp))

    errCount = Application.Evaluate("COUNTIF("& rng.Address &",IsError)")

    If errCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "there were no errors", vbOKOnly
    Else
        MsgBox "there were " & errCount & " errors", vbOKOnly
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: is this code `Application.Worksheetfunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"),IsError)` really working on your machine. I was excited when I sow it but it doesn't work... Am I missing something??

Comment: hmmm untested. the worksheet function `=CountIf("A:A",IsError)` works. I just assumed the VB equivalent would also work. Let me revise!

Comment: @KazJaw fixed. Had to use `Application.Evaluate` and concat the formula. WOrksheet function worked fine (on the worksheet, but not from VBA!). Thanks for catching that.